# How do you plot a series of dichotomous variables and a composite variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot some clinical characteristics of a sample of patients with a particular disease. There are four variables that are dichotomous and if any one of them is TRUE for being aggressive then the patients is labelled as having an aggressive course.
To do just one variable at a time would mean we could use a stacked or dodged bar plot. We could even use a pie chart. 
But to display all the variables and the composite on a  single chart is more challenging.

I created some dummy data (just three characteristics + composite). I cannot believe how many manipulations I had to take the data through to plot what I wanted. I encountered every problem that exists. Each problem needed more manipulation. When I looked for answers (for instance on stackoverflow) I could find nothing, probably because I do not know what the buzz words are to describe what I was trying to do.

*Questions*
**1) What are the buzz words for what I am trying to do**
**2) Does it really need to be this hard or is there are more direct route in ggplot2 that would let me go straight to the chart from the raw data file containing as many rows as there are human subjects**

## created some simulated data

```
require(data.table)
aggr.freq <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.9) )
aggr.count <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.2, 0.8) )
aggr.spread <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size=100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6) )
human.subjects <- data.table(aggr.freq, aggr.count, aggr.spread)
human.subjects[,aggr.course.composite:=aggr.freq|aggr.count|aggr.spread]
```

## tally the trues

```
aggr.true  <-  human.subjects [,list(aggr.freq = sum(aggr.freq), aggr.count = sum(aggr.count), aggr.spread = sum(aggr.spread), aggr.course.composite= sum(aggr.course.composite))]
```

## that tally is in the wrong orientation for plotting

```
aggr.true.vertical <- data.table(t(aggr.true))
aggr.true.vertical[,clinical.characteristic:=factor(dimnames(t(aggr.true))[[1]], ordered=TRUE, levels= c("aggr.freq", "aggr.count", "aggr.spread", "aggr.course.composite"))]#have to specify levels otherwise ggplot2 will plot the variables in alphabetical order
setnames(x=aggr.true.vertical, old = "V1", new = "aggressive")
aggr.true.vertical[,indolent:=human.subjects[,.N]-aggressive]#we had the tally of trues now we need to tall the falses


ggplot(aggr.true.vertical, aes(x=clinical.characteristic, y=aggressive)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") # alas, this graph only shows the count of those with an aggressive characteristic and does not give the reader a feel for the proportion.
```

## reshape for the second time

```
require(reshape2)
long <- melt(aggr.true.vertical, variable.name="aggressiveness",value.name="count")
ggplot(long, aes(x=clinical.characteristic, y=count, fill=aggressiveness)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are going to use data.table syntax, you should include `library(data.table)` as your first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can see what happened in how you were thinking about the problem, but I think you "took a wrong turn" early on in the process. I'm not sure I can help you with the keywords to search on. Anyway, all you need is one melt and then you can plot. After your data generation:

```
human.subjects$id<-1:nrow(human.subjects) # Create an id variable (which you probably have)
melted.humans<-melt(human.subjects,id='id') 
ggplot(melted.humans, aes(x=variable,fill=value)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Maybe you would prefer to flip the order of true and false, but you get the idea.

Also, you may be interested in some simplified code for the other parts of what you were doing, which was counting the trues and falses. (In my solution, I just let `ggplot` do it.)

```
# Count the trues:
sapply(human.subjects,sum)

# Collect all the trues and falses into a single matrix,
# by running table on each column.
sapply(human.subjects,table)
```